# CPT archive 404ing when using a custom taxonomy name as a variable

Tags: permalinks, parameter

So, I'm using a custom post type archive and generating a JavaScript-based filtering interface for sorting through results.

Here's an example: http://www.inverity.org/sermons/

Now, what I'd like to do is pass in variables to my script to allow for filtering based on URL parameters.

This works: http://www.inverity.org/sermons/?presenters=4

The problem is, this doesn't: http://www.inverity.org/sermons/?speakers=4

"speakers" is the name of the custom taxonomy I'm using and is the value that I want to filter by.

Any ideas why this is happening? Is there anything I can do to get around it and prevent the 404ing?

Comment: this is difficult to answer with the information provided. what does the code look like that does the filtering? I suggest inspecting the global `$wp_query` to see the query being generated.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, Milo. I will take a look and report back after investigating further.

Comment: In what way does http://www.inverity.org/sermons/?presenters=4 work? Whatever the number at the end, the results are the same.

Comment: @vancoder It works in the sense that the parameter hits the page, is passed in, and *could* be used in the filtering process (it's not being used, so the results don't change). What I want is for the "speakers" parameter to work without giving me a 404.

Comment: I think we'd need to see some code.

Comment: As far as diagnosis I would try using the plug-in "Debug This" and checking the actual query that gets generated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem on my large project that I currently work on. It's case when you have collision between taxonomy and post-type slugs. Problem is that you can filter by taxonomy with adding `?taxonomy_name=term_slug` and also you can see the custom post by adding `?post_type=custom_post_slug`. So, that's the same syntax, and WP doesn't know do you want "term archive" or "single custom post".

The only, and the right way (in my opinion) to solve this is to change either taxonomy-slug or post_type-slug (probably, it's easier to fix and handle side-effects of renaming the taxonomy, I guess).

## 2nd solution

Also, I found one EXACT solution, you can find the details [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy#Arguments). In the other words, you can set for your `register_taxonomy()` argument `$args['query_var'] = false` with which you disable query parameter `speakers` to act as taxonomy slug. Therefore, if you want to filter by taxonomy terms directly in URL / `$_GET` var, you will have to do some other magic. But, at least, you will remove collision between post_type and taxonomy names.

Optionally, you will have to `flush_rewrite_rules` after that in whatever way you want:

1. Add `flush_rewrite_rules();` in `functions.php`, go to the site, refresh it several times, remove that line and save `functions.php` again.
2. Go to Wordpress admin -> Options -> Permalink and click save.

I usually do both of it. Just in case.

## 3rd solution

Hook custom function to `pre_get_posts()`. With this method, you have to be careful in which case you will edit the query args. Put this in the `functions.php`.

```
function preQueryAction( $query ) {

    // classic approach to avoid messing queries in Admin and custom queries.
    if(is_admin() or !$query->is_main_query()) return; 
    
    // selectively filter only if you are on CPT arhive
    if(is_post_type_archive()){
        $query->set( 'speakers', false );
    }
    
    return;
    
}


add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'preQueryAction', 1 );
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! I had forgotten about disabling query_vars. I'm going to give that a test and report back.

Comment: Great! Glad to hear that problem is solved :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm taking some shots in the dark, here.

The first place I would look is your register_taxonomy call.  You should make sure not to set the query_var option to false.

```
register_taxonomy(
  'speakers',
  array('post'),
  array(
    'rewrite'                    => array( 'slug' => 'media-channel' ),
    'public'                     => true,
    'query_var'                  => 'speakers',
  )
)
```

With that in place you can be certain you can test the query using get_posts.  This test would look like:

```
$test_results = get_posts( array(
                      'post_type' => 'post', 
                      'numberposts' => -1,
                      'speakers' => 4,
                  ) );
```

Did you get results?  On looking at your example I have a strong suspicion that your taxonomy may be associated with attachments.  If that's the case I have had to do add "post_status" => "inherit".

```
$test_results = get_posts( array(
                      'post_status' => 'inherit',
                      'post_type' => 'attachment', 
                      'numberposts' => -1,
                      'speakers' => 4,
                  ) );
```

How does this look to you?  If you're getting results here then maybe there's something going on with the query parameters or rewrite rules.

The codex [register_taxonomy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy) references the need to flush the rewrite rules if you use the 'rewrite' parameter.

```
 global $wp_rewrite;
 $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
```

Now that you're fairly certain that you're getting results from this query you can inspect the query that WordPress is building internally.  This can be done with the excellent plug-in "Debug This" or using:

```
global $wp_query;
print_r($wp_query->query_vars);
```

This will show the query that WordPress constructed using "?speakers=4".